# How to take screenshot with video on the screen

Tags: java, android, cordova, screenshot

im developing an cordova app for android, im writting a plugin for a feature in java but i havent found right way. im trying to solve this problem for a long time. I have tried a lot of codes, but it doesnt work. There is a video on the page which I want to take a screenshot. When i take screenshot with that codes, the video area looks completely black. i need to taking screenshot code with video area.

Codes i have tried

it works, but with black video area:

```
View view = this.cordova.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

also it works, but with black video area:

```
Display display = this.cordova.getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
View view = 
this.cordova.getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size.x, size.y, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Comment: Hey @abdullah coskun did you find a solution?